# CSS: Background fills on hover from bottom to top:

Tags: html, css

please take a look at this example:

https://www.outsideonline.com/2317131/wilma-rudolph-worlds-fastest-woman

Note that when you **hover over link**, the background animated to fill the anchor text **from bottom to top**, and clears is from top to bottom when you hover away from it.

I've done something similar with my own website. The relevant CSS for it:

```
a {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 -1px #FFF986;
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
    transition: box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
    color: black;
}

a:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 40px #FFF986;
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
    transition: box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}
```

This gives me a similar effect, but instead of filling from top to bottom like in the example link: The background starts to fill from all sides of the rectangle toward to center.

How do I force it to fill from top to bottom, like in the example link I shared? what am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're changing wrong parameter:

`a:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -40px 0 -1px #FFF986;`

```css
a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 -1px #FFF986;
  transition: box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
  color: black;
  line-height: 40px;
}

a:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -40px 0 -1px #FFF986;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Hey Mickey!</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! that did the trick. I get was I did wrong.  BTW: it now fills from top to bottom, not bottom to top -- but that's ok. I'll figure it out.

Comment: Thanks, the minus made the directional difference !

Comment: @JasonGenX, happy to help!

Answer (score 5):

Another solution that uses a 50%/50% linear gradient resized to 200%. To animate the background change the background position:

```css
a {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, yellow 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  background-position: top;
  transition: background-position 0.5s ease-in-out; /** I've changed the time for demo purposes **/
  color: black;
}

a:hover {
  background-position: bottom;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">I'm a link</a>
<a href="#">I'm another link</a>
```

Comment: you can also make easier like this : https://jsfiddle.net/80rm4duk/1/ ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif - I know that one as well, but I thought mine was easier :)

Comment: well, mine is actually *filling* from bottom to top but yours *moving* from bottom to top and in the question we want the fills ... (kidding ! :p).

Answer (score 0):

```css
a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 -1px #FFF986;
  transition: box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
  color: black;
  line-height: 40px;
}

a:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -40px 0 -1px #FFF986;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Hey Mickey!</a>
```

Comment: That really works nice! Thanks.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51562411/17175441). If you just wanted to comment on that answer then once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) and [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful