# Set own styles to content in before element

Tags: html, css

I've just created a button. I've found a problem where my content doesn't fit on it's place.

Here is my code:

```css
.btn-red {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 13px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  background: #f42f2c;
  font: 10px "Oswald", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.4em;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: color 0.1s linear 0.05s;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 1px solid #f42f2c;
}
.btn-red:focus {
  box-shadow:none !important;
}
.btn-red::before {
  content: "READ MORE";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #f9f9ff;
  color:#f42f2c !important;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: height 0.2s ease, top 0.2s ease, opacity 0s linear 0.2s;
}
.btn-red::after {
  transition: border 0.1s linear 0.05s;
}
.btn-red .btn-red-inner {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.btn-red:hover {
  transition: color 0.1s linear 0s;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f42f2c !important;
}
.btn-red:hover::before {
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: height 0.2s ease, top 0.2s ease, opacity 0s linear 0s;
}
.btn-red:hover::after {
  transition: border 0.1s linear 0s;
}
```

```html
<a href="o-nas.php" class="btn-red">
            <span class="btn-inner">READ MORE</span>
        </a>
```

I tried to add `padding: 13px 20px` to `.btn-red::before`, but it has some bugs and I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: are you open to a different idea to do the same effect? ex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56633103/8620333

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I achieve the same thing that you wanted without using `:before` to control the button text. Look below:

```css
.btn-red {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 13px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #f42f2c;
  border: 1px solid #f42f2c;
}

.btn-red:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  content: "";
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: height 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-red .btn-inner {
  font: 10px "Oswald", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1em;
  letter-spacing: 0.4em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-red:hover:before {
  height: 100%;
}

.btn-red:hover .btn-inner {
  color: #f42f2c;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn-red" href="#" title="Read More">
  <span class="btn-inner">Read more</span>
</a>
```

Hope this can help you anyway. If you have any doubt about the code, please, just let me know :)

Cheers!

Comment: No problem at all, @MatějČerný :)